# HTML not working - PHP/GD Lib

Tags: php, gd

I want to have a "Print This Image" button on the page where the image is generated. Ive tried putting html code on my **image.php** file(see codes below)  but it wont show. Some people said  to try separating the html and php code. Ive tried using the  `<img src="image.php" alt="" />` code on another file called **generated.php** but all I get is a broken image. Please help! :(

Here is the code of my **image.php** file:

```
$num_fields = $_POST['num_fields'];
// create image
$image = imagecreate(500, 500);

// allocate some colors
$white    = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
$pink     = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 105, 180);
$red = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 000, 000);
$green     = imagecolorallocate($image, 034, 139, 034);
$brown = imagecolorallocate($image, 139, 069, 019);
$yellow      = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 000);
$orange  = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 140, 000);
$blue  = imagecolorallocate($image, 100, 149, 237);
$purple  = imagecolorallocate($image, 218, 112, 214);
$gray  = imagecolorallocate($image, 205, 205, 193);
$black    = imagecolorallocate($image, 000, 000, 000);
$cyan    = imagecolorallocate($image, 000, 255, 255);


//bg color//
imagefilledrectangle($image,0,0,500,500,$white);

$font = 'arial.ttf'; 

if($num_fields =='6')
{ 
// for each slices
imagefilledarc($image, 250, 250, $_POST['rating-1'], $_POST['rating-1'], 0, 60, $pink, IMG_ARC_EDGED);
imagefilledarc($image, 250, 250, $_POST['rating-2'], $_POST['rating-2'], 60, 120 , $green, IMG_ARC_EDGED);
imagefilledarc($image, 250, 250, $_POST['rating-3'], $_POST['rating-3'], 120, 180 , $red, IMG_ARC_EDGED);
imagefilledarc($image, 250, 250, $_POST['rating-4'], $_POST['rating-4'], 180, 240 , $gray, IMG_ARC_EDGED);
imagefilledarc($image, 250, 250, $_POST['rating-5'], $_POST['rating-5'], 240, 300 , $orange, IMG_ARC_EDGED);
imagefilledarc($image, 250, 250, $_POST['rating-6'], $_POST['rating-6'], 300, 360 , $blue, IMG_ARC_EDGED);


//outline
imagefilledarc($image, 250, 250, 400, 400, 0,360, $black, IMG_ARC_NOFILL); //outer circle
imagefilledarc($image, 250, 250, 320, 320, 0,360, $black, IMG_ARC_NOFILL); //inner circle
imageline($image, 250, 250, 450, 250, $black ); //line bet blue and pink 0 deg
imageline($image, 250, 250, 349, 78, $black ); //line bet orange and blue
imageline($image, 250, 250, 150, 78, $black ); //line bet orange and gray 
imageline($image, 250, 250, 50, 250, $black ); //line bet red and gray 
imageline($image, 250, 250, 151, 422, $black ); //line bet red and green 
imageline($image, 250, 250, 350, 422, $black ); //line bet pink and green 


//text legends 2
imagettftext($image, 9, 243, 425, 280, $black, $font, $_POST['field-1']);
imagettftext($image, 9, 183, 315, 415, $black, $font, $_POST['field-2']);
imagettftext($image, 9, 120, 130, 380, $black, $font, $_POST['field-3']);
imagettftext($image, 9, 60, 75, 210, $black, $font, $_POST['field-4']);
imagettftext($image, 9,0, 200, 80, $black, $font, $_POST['field-5']);
imagettftext($image, 9, 300, 378, 128, $black, $font, $_POST['field-6']);


// flush image
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($image);
imagedestroy($image);   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bit unclear to me what you want, but... The code you are showing is just making the image. In addition to this, you need an html page made by some scripting language that forwards the queries to your image.php e.g. (this is quite old fashioned php-coding and looks ugly, but it should work)

```
<html>
<head><title>My image</title></head>
<body>
<img src="image.php?<?php
    print"num_fields=${_POST['num_fields']}&rating-1=${_POST['rating-1']}&rating-2=${_POST['rating-2']}&rating-3=${_POST['rating-3']}&rating-4=${_POST['rating-4']}&rating-5=${_POST['rating-5']}&rating-6=${_POST['rating-6']}&field-1=${_POST['field-1']}&field-2=${_POST['field-2']}&field-3=${_POST['field-3']}&field-4=${_POST['field-4']}&field-5=${_POST['field-5']}&field-6=${_POST['field-6']}"
?>
" alt="" /> 
</body>
</html>
```

(The "My image" part may of course be anything you like as a title for your page)

Now you can start to add on something more between the  and  tags. If you add some html output in the file you have now, it will either be ignored or it will make your image invalid.

Comment: Yes I already did that. But I still get a broken image. Okay the scenario is this: I have an index.php file where the user will input some data like rating, field and num_field. The form from index.php file now sends the data to that image.php file where it will make a pie chart using GD lib which it outputs on the browser as an image. Now my problem is I want to put a "Print this image" button on the page together with the pie chart image produced by the image.php file. But i dont know where to put my code for the button.If i try to put it in image.php file, it is ignored.

Comment: Ahh, I understand, have a look at my updated answer. You must of course use scripting (e.g. php) so that you can forward the query string to the image.php (and as I said, that is really quick and dirty php, but it should work - I hope)

Comment: I also tried putting this code include('image.php'); instead of the <img> tag but i get header warning and some random characters which i guess is from the image. Can you help me figure out whats wrong with this?

Comment: include() will not work here. The output from the image.php - with the query string (num_fields and all your rating and fields variables) is just an image - and the way to show an image in an html-file is to use the img-tag. Did you try my updated example? Save it as e.g. showimage.php and let the index.html point to that rather than to the image.php file.

Comment: And also, for this to work, you need to change the _POST to _GET throughout image.php

Comment: I have to admit, there was a but in the first phpexample I made, but now it should work - just as a starting point. :-)

Comment: Is there really { } on this code  print"num_fields=${_POST['num_fields']}&rating ?

Comment: yep. the {} is needed for php to parse the variable correctly. (I tested the code, so it should work just as it is)

Comment: I followed all you have said, but I still get a broken image.

Comment: ah thank you so much! Its working now. I just missed some few codes. Thanks a lot!